# jquery dialog load issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm just trying to play around with Jquery dialog.  I click a button and the dialog appears.  This code is just straight copy from Jquery docs (well, through a link to a blog post).

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var js = jQuery.noConflict();

js(document).ready(function() {
var $dialog = js('<div></div>')
    .html('This dialog will show every time!')
    .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Basic Dialog'
    });

js('#axis-details').click(function() {
    $dialog.dialog('open');
    // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
    return false;
});
});
</script>
```

The simple html button:

```
<button id="axis-details" >API Key</button>
```

I get this error: `js("<div></div>").html("This dialog will show every time!").dialog is not a function`

First I want to make sure I didn't do anything wrong with the code here. Typically this means it is not loading the jquery-ui appropriately but I can see with firebug it is loaded fine.  I also make sure it doesn't conflict with any other package, hence the noConflict().

Any hints where I'm going wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems to be some bugs with using .noConflict(), especially with jQuery UI. Check out the comments at the bottom of the api page for noConflict: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: sounds like you may be loading jQuery again in page somewhere else, which will wipe out jQueryUI being part of jQuery object

Comment: Yes, your code works fine when isolated: http://jsfiddle.net/JvuY7/

Comment: Thanks all, @Travis J is right.  There is some sort of conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Travis J had this right.  Seems like there is some sort of conflict with .noConflict() and jQuery UI.  How ironic ;)

Removing noConflict() makes this work.

Answer (score 2):

[copied to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MpDjY/)

And it works fine.  Your problem must be outside of this bit of code